# Audex unavailable in 20.04LTS

Tags: cd-ripping

My favourite CD ripper [Audex](https://www.linux-apps.com/content/show.php?content=77125) [more](https://github.com/KDE/audex/blob/master/README.md) doesn't seem to be in the repositories for 20.04LTS, and installing the last available version in 16.04 LTS doesn't work because kde-runtime isn't available. Is it available by any other means? thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/KDE/audex compile and build from source to install

Comment: See answer below, it compiles normally on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Qt5 and KF5.

Answer (score 2):

The source code on github has [mentions of Qt5 and KF5](https://github.com/KDE/audex/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L35), so I was preliminary wrong about its obsolescence.

We can compile and install it:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake extra-cmake-modules \
qt5-default dh-buildinfo docbook2x libcdparanoia-dev pkg-kde-tools \
qtscript5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libkf5plasma-dev \
libkf5completion-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev \
libkf5kcmutils-dev libkf5kio-dev libkf5cddb-dev

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/KDE/audex.git
cd audex
cmake .
make -j3

sudo make install
```

And then use it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using N0rbert's instructions for a while, but now qt5-default is deprecated and has no installation candidate.  So instead of qt5-default, add these packages:

```
apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools libkf5textwidgets*
```

The make process throws a lot of warnings about deprecated declarations in the code, but it still compiles and works.