# How to correctly run graphical application in schroot with Qt and D-Bus?

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, qt, chroot, dbus

I was trying to get Audex [running](https://askubuntu.com/q/1244294/66509) inside 16.04 LTS [`schroot`](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) on the 20.04 LTS host.

The below method works normally for Gtk-based applications, I have tested it.

In current case I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/xenial.conf
[xenial]
description=Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
directory=/srv/chroot/xenial
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/xenial

sudo debootstrap xenial /srv/chroot/xenial

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /srv/chroot/xenial/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

schroot -c xenial -u root apt-get update
schroot -c xenial -u root apt-get install audex
```

Then try to launch it from terminal

```
schroot -c xenial env DISPLAY=:0.0 audex
```

And got the following terminal output:

> ```
> QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
> QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. QDBusConnection: session
> D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may
> misbehave. Failed enumerating UDisks2 objects:
> "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected"   "Not connected to D-Bus
> server"  Failed enumerating UDisks2 objects:
> "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected"   "Not connected to D-Bus
> server"  Failed enumerating UDisks2 objects:
> "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected"   "Not connected to D-Bus
> server"  Failed enumerating UDisks2 objects:
> "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected"   "Not connected to D-Bus
> server"  Failed enumerating UDisks2 objects:
> "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected"   "Not connected to D-Bus
> server"  Failed enumerating UDisks2 objects:
> "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected"   "Not connected to D-Bus
> server"  KCrash: Application 'audex' crashing... KCrash: Attempting to
> start /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit KCrash: Connect
> sock_file=/home/mate/.kde/socket-focal/kdeinit4__0 Warning: connect()
> failed: : No such file or directory KCrash: Attempting to start
> /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi directly audex(2145): Communication
> problem with  "audex" , it probably crashed.  Error message was: 
> "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply" : " "Message recipient
> disconnected from message bus without replying" " 
>
> drkonqi(2154): Unable to find an internal debugger that can work with
> the KCrash backend  drkonqi(2154): The specified process does not
> exist.
> ```

and application window was not shown.

I suppose I have a problem  with D-Bus here. How can we fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
export $(dbus-launch)
```

to run a new message bus daemon before launching other apps